# Flask request.args in Blueprint throws RuntimeError: Working outside of request context

Tags: python, flask

I have my build my application like that:

**main.py**

```
from communication.rest.routes.v1.files import files
from communication.rest.routes.v1.data import data    

APP = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates')
APP.register_blueprint(data, url_prefix='/v1/data')
APP.register_blueprint(files, url_prefix='/v1/files') 
...
```

**data.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, request
data = Blueprint('data', __name__)

@data.route('/days/details', methods=['GET'])
def get_days_details():
   kwargs = request.args.to_dict()
   ...
```

If I want to start my rest-service flask throws an error:

*RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.*

I do not understand what i have done wrong. I could not find a hint in the documentation of Blueprints how to get request.args corretly in an Blueprint

```
line 64, in get_days_details
    kwargs = request.args.to_dict()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 37, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Comment: Could you attach a full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @MikhailBerlinkov It is updated

Comment: Do you invoke the function through a http request?

Comment: It happens when I load my scripts before the server starts

Comment: Oh man, that was the right input for my brain! Just when u said that i double checked if there is a usage of this method from within the modules. There was an old reference calling this method on startup. It doesnt't throw an exception before because before this function just returns some mock up data. So when i changed to requests.args this method got called without an http request. Thanks man you saved my evening ;)

Comment: Should I close it?

Comment: You're welcome. I think you may close it or post an answer and close if you think it might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake. So if you see this Exception on loading of your module, there could be somewhere a call of the function (Not caused by Flask).

This does work if you do not use the request context. But if you use it you can not call it without a request context (normally generated by flask if a request hits your endpoint). For testing there is a method how to solve this problem in the documentation. If you are not testing just check for usage of this function and when it is called.

Thanks for help ;)